# How to get the value inside the (brackets) from SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a SQL query to get value after brackets..

For example, from the input

```
Kingdom of Saudi Arabia (KSA)
```

I need the output of `KSA`.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: By majority vote, I decided you are using Oracle.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace('Kingdom of Saudi Arabi ( KSA )', '^.*[(](.*)[)].*$', '\1')
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, using `substr + instr` combination:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Kingdom of Saudi Arabi ( KSA )' from dual)
  3  select trim(substr(col,
  4                     instr(col, '(') + 1,
  5                     instr(col, ')') - instr(col, '(') - 1
  6                    )) result
  7  from test;

RES
---
KSA

SQL>
```